# SEDE query to find users with exactly one post in a particular tag

Tags: optimization, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stackexchange

I'm doing some research for a meta post on [Gardening.SE](http://gardening.stackexchange.com) (where I'm a pro tempore moderator). I'm using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) to find information about first time users who post questions in our [identification] tag, and how they subsequently interact with the people who respond to their question, whether that's comments on the post, comments on answers, editing the post to provide more information, and so on.

I have the following query which gives me the list of people with no answers and one question that includes the [identification] tag. I plan to refine it by adding extra criteria, e.g. to find instances where the OP leaves a comment replying to someone else.

```
-- Find users who have exactly one post
-- with that post being a question
-- and the question has the [identification] tag
SELECT
  Users.Id AS [User Link], Posts.Id AS [Post Link]
FROM
  Users INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
        INNER JOIN PostTags ON Posts.Id = PostTags.PostId
        INNER JOIN Tags ON Tags.Id = PostTags.TagId
WHERE
  Tags.TagName LIKE 'identification' AND
  Posts.ParentId IS NULL AND   -- ParentId is NULL if post is a question
  Users.Id in (
    -- Users with exactly one question
    SELECT Users.Id
    FROM 
      Users INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
    WHERE
      Posts.ParentId IS NULL
    GROUP BY
      Users.id
    HAVING
      Count(Posts.Id) = 1
    ) AND
  Users.Id NOT IN (
      -- Users with 1 or more answers
    SELECT Users.Id
    FROM 
      Users INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
    WHERE
      Posts.ParentId IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      Users.id
    HAVING
      Count(Posts.Id) > 0
    )
ORDER BY 
  Users.Id DESC  -- newest users first.
```

My concern is that this SQL is far from optimal. I'm looking especially at the repeated inner joins between the Users and Posts tables, and the similarity between the sub-queries to find users with one question and users with at least one answer.

[Gardening.SE](http://gardening.stackexchange.com) is a small site, so this query consistently takes less than 75ms to return its 101 records, but even so I'd like to make it run more efficiently, if possible. As I said, I plan to enhance this query, which will mean pulling in more tables, so I'm also concerned about it scaling that way.

Data Explorer links:

- [Users with one [identification] question and no answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/gardening/query/182080/users-with-one-identification-question-and-no-answers) — the above query.
- [Drive-by users with one [identification] question](http://data.stackexchange.com/gardening/query/181790/drive-by-users-with-one-identification-question) — a derived query for users who post and are never seen again.

Comment: Hey, and welcome to CR... we have a long history of messing with SEDE too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half of the tricks with optimizing SQL is knowing the database schema.

The schema documentation can be found in this Meta post: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

There are four functional issues I see with your query, and a couple of suggestions after that:

1. Use PostTypeId - it describes what the Post is (Question == 1, Answer == 2) and is well indexed.
2. you are querying closed posts (which have a non-null `ClosedDate`)
3. you join to `Tags` for a single record. This can be resolved independantly
4. you have Posts three times in your query, and it can be there only twice if you do double-duty in the 'Only One Question' part of the query....

As for the suggestions:

- I like parametrize things, and being able to change the tag you are interested makes sense, so I would parametrize that.
- The SQL Server syntax allows for 'with' sections in a query, and that makes the code a lot more readable than the query-in-from-clause syntax

Using these suggestions I restructured your query to do a few things:

- add a User-Name sort column (SEDE does not sort [User Link] columns well)
- parametrized the tag, with a default value of `identification`
- made the group-by and having a much smaller component in the query.
- added the closed-query support (and community-wiki - if there are).

[I forked your query here...](http://data.stackexchange.com/gardening/query/182103/users-with-one-identification-question-and-no-answers?tag=identification) ... for me it ran through in 33 milliseconds

```
-- Find users who have exactly one post
-- with that post being a question
-- and the question has the [xxxx] tag (default identification)

declare @tag as nvarchar(25) = ##tag:string?identification##
;
declare @tagid as int
;

-- get the tag id here so it is not needed as a join table
select @tagid = Id
from Tags
where TagName = lower(@tag)

;

print 'Tag for ' + @tag + ' is ' + Convert(NVarchar(10), @tagid)

;

with Answerers as (

    select distinct OwnerUserId as [UserId]
    from Posts p
    where PostTypeId = 2 -- answers
      and CommunityOwnedDate is null -- not CW
      and ClosedDate is null -- not closed

), SingleQ as (

    Select OwnerUserId as [UserId],
           Min(Id) as [FirstPost],
           Sum(Score) as [Score],
           count (*) as [QCount]
    from Posts p
    where PostTypeId = 1 -- question
      and CommunityOwnedDate is null -- not CW
      and ClosedDate is null -- not closed
      and not exists (
            select UserId
            from Answerers
            where UserId = OwnerUserId) -- active answerers.
    group by OwnerUserId
    having count(*) = 1
)

SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by Users.Id Desc) as [Recent],
  Users.Id AS [User Link],
  Users.DisplayName AS [Sort By Name],
  SingleQ.FirstPost AS [Post Link],
  SingleQ.Score AS [Score]
FROM Users 
     INNER JOIN SingleQ ON Users.Id = SingleQ.UserId
     INNER JOIN PostTags ON SingleQ.FirstPost = PostTags.PostId
WHERE PostTags.TagId = @tagid
ORDER BY 
  Users.Id DESC  -- newest users first.
```